# Adding a row at the bottom of a DataFrame for a grand total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am grouping information from an Excel file with Pandas, with this information i am summing the values in order to get a summary of the data.

It's pulling certain info from an excel, then grouping columns in order to reflect the summary i want.

```
summary_df = df.groupby(["NAME", "CITY"])["QUANTITY"].sum().reset_index()
summary_df.loc["Grand Total"] = summary_df["QUANTITY"].sum()
```

This is returning the information I want AND giving me the summed total but it is showing the quantity summary on each of the columns for the dataframe like this:

```
NAME         |   CITY   |   QUANTITY
JOHN         |  LONDON  |     50
STEVE        |  PARIS   |     100
GRAND TOTAL  |   150    |     150
```

I only want to see the grand total under QUANTITY and no other columns.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add your total row to your `groupby` series and *then* convert to a dataframe via `reset_index`. Currently, you are populating the entire row of a dataframe with a scalar, which triggers Pandas to use broadcasting.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 'LONDON', 10], ['A', 'LONDON', 20],
                   ['B', 'CHICAGO', 30], ['C', 'CHICAGO', 20]],
                  columns=['NAME', 'CITY', 'QUANTITY'])

df_summary = df.groupby(['NAME', 'CITY'])['QUANTITY'].sum()
df_summary.loc['Grand Total'] = df_summary.sum()

df_summary = df_summary.reset_index()

print(df_summary)

          NAME     CITY  QUANTITY
0            A   LONDON        30
1            B  CHICAGO        30
2            C  CHICAGO        20
3  Grand Total                 80
```